# What is the correct way to keep open a user session in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, session-timeout

I use https to log my users in a CakePHP 2.4.7 application.

According to the documentation, my core.php contains that lines :

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 1440 // 24 hours
));
```

But my user sessions continue to timeout about each hour.
What is wrong, or what I am missing ?

Comment: you could check if your cookie lifetime is correct, it should be sure but it is better to doublecheck it

Comment: check session.gc_maxlifetime. If sessions are expiring it's not CakePHP that's doing it, you need to identify the cause (one way to do that is make the session file/storage-folder readonly and look for an error message as something tries to delete it). Another typical scenario is that the session is being hammered/invalidated (parallel 404 requests hitting your application can cause the session id to be updated, leaving the session cookie with an id different than that on the server).  OR: it's application/server/developer specific. Appart from advice you're not likely to get an answer.

Comment: @Soulan my cookie expires 24 hours later as the config says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @AD7six:

The problem was in my php.ini configuration :

```
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Here the time is counted in seconds, not minutes, so, to match the configuration

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 1440 // 24 hours
));
```

I need :

```
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
; 24 hours: 1440*60
```